Inject JobLauncherTestUtils without using the @Autowired in unit test and spring batch
I'm new with Spring Batch and I'm trying to create an unit test for my job without using spring Boot and spring Batch annotations, only the mockito, however when i mock the JobLauncherTestUtils my jobExecution is always null.
here is my unit test:
class MyjobConfigurationTest {

 MyjobConfiguration myjobConfiguration = Mockito.mock(MyjobConfiguration.class);
 JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils = Mockito.mock(JobLauncherTestUtils.class);

@Test
void whenJobExecuted_thenSuccess() throws Exception {
        
        JobExecution jobExecution =
                jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(
                        new JobParametersBuilder().addString("timestamp",
                         LocalDateTime.now().toString())
                         .toJobParameters()); // return null

        JobInstance actualJobInstance = jobExecution.getJobInstance(); // nullPointerException
        ExitStatus actualJobExitStatus = jobExecution.getExitStatus();


        assertThat(actualJobInstance.getJobName(), is("myJob"));
        assertThat(actualJobExitStatus.getExitCode(), is("COMPLETED"));
        
    }

here is my MyjobConfiguration:
@Bean
    public Job myJob(
            final Step convertStep,
            final Step writeStep,
            final Optional<JobListener> jobListener,
            final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory
    ) {
        SimpleJobBuilder builder = jobBuilderFactory
                .get("myJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(convertStep)
                .next(writeStep);

        jobListener.ifPresent(builder::listener);

        return builder.build();
    }

I'm facing a nullPointerException in jobExcecution and I'm not sure what to change/add to mock the behavior JobExecution by using only the jobExecution.

The implementation of MyJobConfiguration does not matter, because you create a Mockito.mock for it. A mock is a lifeless shell without any behavior. It only returns the values that you stub with Mockito.when; the default is to return null (and empty collection-like objects). Your test doesn't test anything besides that Mockito would work (if you had stubbed return values). The real method myJob is never called by your test.
